# TensorFlow automatically modify my variable scope name?

Tags: tensorflow

check following code:

**code:**

```
with tf.variable_scope('test'): # <1>
    v1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(10,10), name='v1') # <2>

with tf.variable_scope('test'): # <3>
    v2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5, 5), name='v2')
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

In code <3>, I wanna add a new placeholder named v2 into variable scope 'test' which exists a placeholder named v1. However, **print result shows following**

```
Tensor("test/v1:0", shape=(10, 10), dtype=float32)

Tensor("test_1/v2:0", shape=(5, 5), dtype=float32)
```

**I dont know why TF modify variable scope name 'test' into 'test_1'?Is it a BUG?**

**EDIT:**

I find that not only placeholer will be modified its variable scope name, but all ops in tensorflow such as add and matmul will be modified. But adding variable by `tf.get_variable()` is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find answer in github, check [issue15575](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15575#issuecomment-353541003)